# Avoid iOS video compression with Cordova camera.getPicture()

Tags: ios, cordova, video

Is there a way to avoid the iOS video compression when selecting a video from the gallery with `camera.getPicture()`?

```
var options = {
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  mediaType: 1
}

navigator.camera.getPicture(videoGallerySuccess, videoGalleryError, options);
```

The user has to wait for the video compression to be finished when selecting a video.

I would like to avoid this and instead do my own compression whenever the user has submitted a form for example.

[image: iOS Video Compression]

Answer (score 0):

In [Cordova Camera Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera) you need to define a quality of the final video/photo. According documentation, default value for all media types is 50. To prevent a loss of resolution (and potentially video processing) set quality to 100.

```
var options = {
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  mediaType: 1,
  quality: 100
}

navigator.camera.getPicture(videoGallerySuccess, videoGalleryError, options);
```

Comment: After some testing I can't see that `quality` affects video. It's still compressing regardless of what I set `quality` too. Can't see anything in the documentation either stating that it affects video, only images.